# UITableView reloadData not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm working on an app, in which I'm calculating data in a loop and for each cycle I want to publish new section in tableview showing that calculated result. I'm adding results to an array and calling `tableView.reloadData()`. Problem is, the UI is not updating after each loop, but only after the last loop of the cycle and everything is done.

Some notes:

- Delegation and dataSource are connected correctly, as the method is working, just not whenever I want
- I also tried dispatching the whole loop into async block
- I tried calling the `reloadData()` alone in an async block (lot's of sources advised to try this)
- I tried loads of combinations including functions `beginUpdates, endUpdates, reload/insert sections/rows`. You get the drift.
- When calling `reloadData()`, numberOfSections method is always called, but the cellForRow only after the whole work is done
- For cells I'm using custom cells with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` property on the tableView. This ensures that multiline text is shown correctly. I really want to believe my constraints on the cells are fine.

Computation code overview:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {

    for i in 0..<data.count {

        // Do computationally intensive work

        results[i].append(result) // multidimensional array
        Util.safeInc(&doneCounter) // made thread-safe just in case with objc_sync_enter
        resultTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Following are the tableView functions. I have created an expandable tableview. Also have some header functions, to create padding between sections, and selection function. They don't seem to be important here.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if expandedCells.contains(section) {
        return results[section].count + 1
    } else {
        return 1
    }

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return doneCounter
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("titleCell") as! electionNameTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = ...
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("resultCell") as! resultTableViewCell
        // set texts for cell labels

        return cell
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my own queue + dispatching `reloadData()` to the main queue from it.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.workQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    for i in 0..<data.count {
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) {
            // Do computationally intensive work
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                resultTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `resultTableView.reloadData()` on the main thread like so :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) {
   resultTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned (5th note), this is advised in most places, but for whatever reason this works even less, as not even `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is called when I do that.

Comment: I read that, but it wasn't clear that you called it on the main thread. For the computing part, did you try to change the logic like call a completion block after each "loop", who calls reload data + itself until all the calculation is done ?